# What is the "vsts_azpcontainer" directory?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

When using azure devops pipline, some templates adding env variables like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.local/bin
```

I am curious about what is this "vsts_azpcontainer" directory.

I googled it but not much useful information found.

Is this a name convention or a pre-defined directory within MS host agent?

Btw I am using the 'Ubuntu-latest' pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default user name of the hosted Ubuntu agent which you used. And the container created the name folder for your current account. That is designed by that. You could find some related info under [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/g47tjr/can_i_disable_user_vsts_to_be_created_in_a/) and [that link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2619).

And actually, this is no such official document to introduce it.